# Is the axiom of constraints always valid?

Tags: classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

> Theoretical Mechanics, S. Targ, p. 28,
>
> > **Axiom of Constraints**: Any constrained body can be treated as a free body relieved from its constraints, provided the latter are represented by their reactions.

Is the above axiom always valid?  Does it apply for a deformable (non-rigid) body?

Comment: While you reference it correctly in the body of the question, you should *not* come away from that book with the impression that the phrase "axiom of constraints" is in common usage or widely understood. (... in light of which, you should consider carefully the title of this post.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Ok I understand

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'm sorry. I have edited it.